# Is it possible to get an array's key name and set it as its own value?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array I'm trying to set the key's name as the value of said key.  I have a form I'm pulling `POST` values from and the name of the key is the name of the form field, so I thought instead of being redundant I'd try this:

```
$fields = array(
    'txtName' => $this->input->post('txtName'), ) //very pseudo
);
```

I was thinking I could just make the array's key the same name as the `field` in the form and then use the key's name as the value.  Something like `'txtName' => $this->input->post(this.key.name)` (very pseudo).

Is this possible?

Comment: So, essentially, `$array = $_POST`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using CodeIgniter, try this:

```
$array = $this->input->post();
```

Comment: @luc-henrdriks Care to add more commentry to your answer and explain how/why this works as it is a new one to me and it has peaked my interest. I did not know PHP had $this (assuming its the same as javascript this), and how/what is the pipe you use (the -> is also new to me) ? Much appreciated...

Comment: `$this` references the class you're in. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: Is it weird that it's only adding my radio buttons to the POST array?  Even when I fill out the Input text fields.

Comment: The syntax in the question looks a lot like Codeigniter, the documentation of that function is here: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html

Did you give your input text values a `name=''` attribute? Are the names unique?